# 204 Error - Hubspot Form Error

Tags: php, forms, hubspot

I am trying to integrate HubSpot into a custom form and my PHP knowledge is limited. So any help would be very much appreciated.

When submitting my form i am getting a log of 204. When I go to my form submissions I can see an entry but no data is being carried across.

Bellow is my form code.
HTML:

```
<input id="first_name" class="hs-input" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="given-name" value="" required>
<input id="lastname" class="hs-input" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="family-name" value="" required>
<input id="phonenumber" class="hs-input" name="phone_number" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" required>
<input value="Submit" typeI"submit">
```

And i am using the PHP script from this link:
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form

Thanks

Comment: You got any answer, i have same issue?

Answer (score 0):

A `204` status code is actually a success status code;

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.

*[HTTP Protocol definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)*

So basically it tells you; "Hey, I'm all good. Data received and processed". You don't need additional information do you? Only when it fails you would want to know *why* it fails.

When you copied the script form the Hubspot API docs, did you notice this line?

```
//Need to populate these variable with values from the form.
```

The variables right below that line (`$firstname`, `$lastname`, etc) don't actually exist yet. You will have to add something like this before that line;

```
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
// etc.
```